# Comparison of strings and writing back in java

Tags: java, string

If two strings are same then the string should be written back into another string how can I do it in Java??

Like,

```
if(s1.equals(s2)==0)
{
    s1;
}
```

Comment: what's the question here?  How to compare 2 strings for equality?

Comment: **Not actually, but resembles the same after checking for equality if equal it should be written to a string**

Comment: Uh oh, the question is in Inglish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String newString = s1.equals(s2) ? s1 : "";//requals returns boolean type true/false and not integer like other languages.
```

Comment: Do you mean tertiary comparison, but what does that empty string do? Could you explain it?

Comment: Its ternary. So if two strings are not equal then newString will hold an empty data while if they are equal then it will hold value of s1.

Answer (score 0):

```
String string1 = "foo";
String string2 = "FOO";
String newstring="";


if (string1.equals(string2))
{

  newstring=string1;

}
```

Comment: more precisely, instead of printing, should be retreived or copied to another or same string

Comment: check my edits: you can copy it to another string . by the same string you always have the same value of string1 , strin1.equals does not change its value

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Java strings are immutable. This isn't C. Once a String is created it can **NEVER** be altered. Are you ready to egg James Gosling's house yet?

If you want a mutable `String` try `StringBuffer` or a `char[]`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    if(s1.equals(s2))
  {
  //then you want to write that s1 will be equal to zero...(if i have undersood correct...)
String new = s1  ;
   }
```

This is the answer if i have understood correctly,but please clarify!

Comment: NO, you're mistaken if both the strings are same then the value of s1 or s2 should be retrieved to another string or one of them